# How to download .gz files from FTP server in R?

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to download all .gz files from this link:
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/

So far I tried this and I am not getting any results:

```
require(RCurl)

url= "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/"
filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")
filenames = unlist(filenames)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Operation timed out after 300552 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes  received
```

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks

EDIT:
I tried to run with with filenames provided to me bellow so in my r script I have:

```
require(RCurl)
my_url <-"ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/"

my_filenames= c("bed_chr_11.bed.gz", ..."bed_chr_9.bed.gz.md5")

my_filenames <- strsplit(my_filenames, "\r\n")
my_filenames = unlist(my_filenames)

for(my_file in my_filenames){
download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile =  file.path('/mydir', my_file))
}
```

And when I run the script I get these warnings:

```
trying URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_11.bed.gz'
```

Error in download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile = file.path("/mydir",  : 
  cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_11.bed.gz'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile = file.path("/mydir",  :
  URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_11.bed.gz': status was 'Timeout was reached'
Execution halted

Comment: Sorry, just for clarification, did the code you posted work for you? I ask because it did for me, so I'm not sure where you're getting the error.

Comment: no, it didn't. It fails after this line:filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

The file names you're trying to access are

```
filenames <- c("bed_chr_11.bed.gz", "bed_chr_11.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_12.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_12.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_13.bed.gz", "bed_chr_13.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_14.bed.gz", "bed_chr_14.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_15.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_15.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_16.bed.gz", "bed_chr_16.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_17.bed.gz", "bed_chr_17.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_18.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_18.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_19.bed.gz", "bed_chr_19.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_20.bed.gz", "bed_chr_20.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_21.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_21.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_22.bed.gz", "bed_chr_22.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_AltOnly.bed.gz", "bed_chr_AltOnly.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_MT.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_MT.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_Multi.bed.gz", "bed_chr_Multi.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_NotOn.bed.gz", "bed_chr_NotOn.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_PAR.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_PAR.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_Un.bed.gz", "bed_chr_Un.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_X.bed.gz", "bed_chr_X.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_Y.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_Y.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_1.bed.gz", "bed_chr_1.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_10.bed.gz", "bed_chr_10.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_2.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_2.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_3.bed.gz", "bed_chr_3.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_4.bed.gz", "bed_chr_4.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_5.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_5.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_6.bed.gz", "bed_chr_6.bed.gz.md5", 
"bed_chr_7.bed.gz", "bed_chr_7.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_8.bed.gz", 
"bed_chr_8.bed.gz.md5", "bed_chr_9.bed.gz", "bed_chr_9.bed.gz.md5"
)
```

The files are big, so I didn't check that this whole loop, but this worked at least for the first file. Add this to the end of your code.

```
my_url <- 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/'
for(my_file in filenames){ # loop over the files
  # download each file, saving in a directory that you need to create on your own computer
  download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile = file.path('c:/users/josep/Documents/', my_file))
}
```

Comment: HI,I am afraid that this line: filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE) never got executed so I can not loop trough filenames

Comment: I can't replicate that error since that step worked fine for me. I'm happy to paste the list of filenames if that would help you.

Comment: please do paste filenames. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's too long for a comment, so I embedded it at the start of the response. That said, if the getURL function didn't work for you, it's possible that download.file won't either.

Comment: I’m doing this on a server, so just to confirm this should be my file.path='t.cri.xxx@something.edu:/sam/mydir’

Comment: It sounds like your R session isn't able to connect to the site for some reason. Obviously you have an internet connection, but maybe R is blocked from it somehow? What is the error download.file gave you?

Comment: it just said that there are more than 50 warnings and exited. I got downloaded only one file: bed_chr_11.bed.gz

Comment: Run warnings() and post one example, if you would.

Comment: Hey I run the script again, please see EDIT part of my post and now I have this new error. What could go wrong?

Comment: That typically happens when you think your code is referring to a variable, but it's actually a function. Just to be safe, directly above the for loop, add the line `my_url <-"ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/"`, then change the first line of the for loop to `for(my_file in filenames){`, and change the body of the loop to `download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile =  file.path('t.cri.xxx@stats.xxx.edu:/scratch/mydir/', my_file))`. Basically add my_ beforeeach of the variable names so they can't conflict with existing functions.

Comment: I did as you wrote above and this is what I got: Error in file.path("t.cri.xxx@stats.xxx.edu:/scratch/mydir/",  : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Calls: download.file -> file.path

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of suggestions. It works fine on my computer, so I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I forgot to change one variable file to my_file. I run it but I got those warnings. Here is one: 49: In download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile = file.path("t.cri.xxx@stats.xxx.edu:/scratch/mydir/",  ... :
  URL ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_AltOnly.bed.gz: cannot open destfile 't.cri.xxx@stats.xxx.edu:/scratch/mydir//bed_chr_AltOnly.bed.gz', reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Do you have a folder called "t.cri.xxx@stats.xxx.edu:/scratch/mydir/" on your computer? That message usually happens when you try to save a file in a directory that doesn't exist. You could try running `dir.create('t.cri.xxx@stats.xxx.edu:/scratch/mydir/', recursive = TRUE)
`

Comment: you were right, it was the path, I fixed it but I got this error: trying URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_11.bed.gz'
Error in download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile = file.path("/scratch/t.cri.asokovic/EQTL",  : 
  cannot open URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_11.bed.gz'
Warning:
In download.file(paste0(my_url, my_file), destfile = file.path("mypath",  :
  URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/bed_chr_11.bed.gz': status was 'Timeout was reached'

Comment: That looks like an internet issue. I think a timeout occurs when R is trying to access a site and isn't getting through. I don't think it's the site, because I'm able to reach it with no problem. Just to see, can you load the `RCurl` package and run `getURL('google.com')`? You should see the result `[1] "<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>301 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF=\"http://www.google.com/\">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"`

Comment: I got it: > getURL('google.com')
[1] "<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>301 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF=\"http://www.google.com/\">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. For some reason you're just not able to communicate with that ftp server. Honestly, at this point you'd probably save time by just pointing your web browser at ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606_b151_GRCh38p7/BED/ and downloading them manually.

Comment: I know it is very peculiar and probably it has to do with the remote server I am doing it on. When I do it manually via wget I just get it hang in this logging phase a long time: Connecting to ftp.ncbi.nih.gov|130.14.250.12|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ...

Comment: it was the issue with the server, it is not possible to download files from external sources. I am new here on stackoverflow, do you mind me asking what I should do now? Should I accept your answer, and write it was the issue with server or?

Comment: You're totally welcome to accept the answer, but I don't think many people are going to encounter the same issues that you did, so I don't think it's too important. My answer isn't likely to be helpful to too many people.